# coldfusion Hide/remove a name from a menu/list

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have an insert form that I did in adobe coldfusion. This insert form inserts information from the men on my team into a databases table called squadreport.  After every insert into my squadreport table, I would like to remove the name of the person that I just inserted from the menu list of available names of those on my team who have not been inserted yet. This way I won’t accidently reinsert their names. The menu list are generated from my  NAMES  tables. The name.foiid field from my NAMES table matches my squadreport.squfoiid field from my SQUADREPORT table.

Example:  If the squadreport.squfoiid is already recorded with the start date of ‘2012-11-18’ and a end date of ‘2012-11-24’, then I want to prevent the reinsertion of same person with the same dates etc.

My current syntax will generate a blank list.

Here’s is what my current syntax look like:

```
<cfquery name="brother" datasource="master">
SELECT name.foiid, squadlt, squadlt.ltid, CONCAT(name.fname,'  ',name.lname) AS teammember
FROM name 
LEFT JOIN  name  ON name.foiid = squadreport.squfoiid
LEFT JOIN squadlt ON ltid = squadreport.sqult
WHERE name.foiid is null
AND squweekbegin =’2012-11-18’
AND squweekend = ‘2012-11-24’
AND squadlt = '3'
AND ltid = '3'
AND CITY = 'sandiego'
AND STATUS <> 'd'
AND STATUS <> 'T'
AND Form4444Complete = 'yes'
ORDER BY teammember
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Is that your actual query? It does not look valid. For example `name` is referenced twice without an alias and what is `squadreport` (table or alias)? Can you post your actual query *and* include the source table for all columns in the `where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're inserting the rows into SquadReport with matching `foiid` columns, you'd just need to exclude the foiid values which exist in the SquadReport table. If there are other conditions like the squad member has to have been activated, or deployed or something, just add it to the exclusion clause.

```
<cfquery name="brother" datasource="master">
SELECT name.foiid, squadlt, squadlt.ltid, CONCAT(name.fname,'  ',name.lname) AS teammember
FROM name 
LEFT JOIN  name  ON name.foiid = squadreport.squfoiid
LEFT JOIN squadlt ON ltid = squadreport.sqult
WHERE name.foiid is null
AND squweekbegin =’2012-11-18’
AND squweekend = ‘2012-11-24’
AND squadlt = '3'
AND ltid = '3'
AND CITY = 'sandiego'
AND STATUS <> 'd'
AND STATUS <> 'T'
AND Form4444Complete = 'yes'
<!--- new code here --->
AND name.foiid NOT IN (SELECT foiid FROM SquadReport)
<!--- end new code --->
ORDER BY teammember
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you basically want to do is to display people not in the table squadreport?  Something like this should work:

```
select name.foiid
, CONCAT(name.fname,'  ',name.lname) AS teammember
from name 
where not exists
(select 1
from squadreport
where squfoiid = name.foiid
and other constraints
)
and other constraints
```

I assume the code you posted is early development code.  Once you go to production you will wanting to use date objects instead of strings and query parameters for any variables.